# Use Unix tools to look for a definition block in an XML.

Tags: grep, utilities, xml

I am using an XML that has definitions in this form -

```
<definition name="ticketOpen" extends="ticketUpdate">
    <put name="title" value="Open Ticket" />
    <put name="mainForm" value="open.jsp" />
    <put name="XYZ" value="PQR" />
            ...
</definition>
```

If I want to search for the definition of "ticketOpen", I can use `grep` like this -

```
grep "definition *name *= *\"ticketOpen\"" definitions.xml
```

However, this only returns the first line of the definition. How can I specify that after finding the first matching line, `grep` (or any other utility) should then look for the closing tag `</definition>` and print all those lines in between them?

Comment: Use a XML parser.  You might want to look at `xmllint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sed:

```
sed -n -e '/definition/,/\/definition/ p' definitions.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

The `xml2` command will convert XML to flat text.

```
$ cat foo.xml 
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<doc name="document">
<object name="foo">
<key name="bar">baz</key>
</object>
<definition name="ticketOpen" extends="ticketUpdate">
<put name="title" value="Open Ticket" />
<put name="mainForm" value="open.jsp" />
<put name="XYZ" value="PQR" />
</definition>
</doc>
$ xml2 < foo.xml 
/doc/@name=document
/doc/object/@name=foo
/doc/object/key/@name=bar
/doc/object/key=baz
/doc/definition/@name=ticketOpen
/doc/definition/@extends=ticketUpdate
/doc/definition/put/@name=title
/doc/definition/put/@value=Open Ticket
/doc/definition/put
/doc/definition/put/@name=mainForm
/doc/definition/put/@value=open.jsp
/doc/definition/put
/doc/definition/put/@name=XYZ
/doc/definition/put/@value=PQR
```

I don't know what the rest of your XML document looks like, but assuming this is the only instance of `definition` you can directly `grep` for it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is something that would be more appropriate to use xpath.  If that is an option, I can get up a sample command line.

This command is available in ubuntu from the package `libxml-xpath-perl`.